# why curl_exec isnt sending the Authorization token to the server?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am trying to send a GET request to a python server with an Authorization Token in the header.

I do receive the Request on the server side but without the authorization token

**Here is the php code that is generating the request :**

```
<?php

$url = "http://localhost:7432/f.php";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array(
 "Authorization: sdfascvthsgdgdssgvsgscf",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
?>
```

When I generate the request from **Reqbin**, I do Receive the request with the Authorization token in the header , but when I try to generate the request from the php file then it does not send the Authorization token to the server

**Here is the request received on server side when I use the Reqbin website to make the request:**

> ```
> 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2021 13:27:10] "GET /f.php HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> Host: localhost:7432
> Connection: keep-alive
> sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="92", "Opera";v="78"
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159
> Safari/537.36 OPR/78.0.4093.184
> sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
> Authorization: sdfascvthsgdgdssgvsgscf
> Accept: */*
> Sec-Fetch-Site: none
> Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
> Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
> Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1359401486.1622671713
> ```

**And This is the received Request when I use the php code mentioned above :**

> ```
>  127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2021 13:27:20] "GET /f.php HTTP/1.1" 200 - 
>  Host: localhost:7432Connection: keep-alive Cache-Control: max-age=0
>  sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="92", "Opera";v="78"
>  sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 User-Agent:
>  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>  like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36 OPR/78.0.4093.184
>  Accept:
>  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
>  Sec-Fetch-Site: none Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
>  Sec-Fetch-Dest: document Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9 Cookie:
>  _ga=GA1.1.1359401486.1622671713
> ```

**What am I doing wrong at the php side ?**

Comment: The usual format for an Authorization header value is `<type> <credentials>` - are you really just sending what you have shown?

Comment: @CBroe Yes I am sending exactly the same thing that I have posted above, in the reqbin website there is an option for sending different types of auth tokens , like basic , or with the login credentials, and the third option is to send just custom token I used custom token , and when I send it using reqbin everything works , but not when I send the same thing from php

Comment: Why, what kind of authorization scheme is that supposed to be? I am guessing that cURL perhaps filters this out, due to the "invalid" format?

Comment: Not sure if it does , but the php code itself is the same code that reqbin is using to send the request , because Its the code that reqbin generated for the request , so I just copied the exact same code

Comment: So what happens when you try to send something like `Authorization: Bearer sdfascvthsgdgdssgvsgscf` instead, does the header make it to the server then?

Comment: Nope it  still don't make it to the server

Comment: Try `"Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode('sdfascvthsgdgdssgvsgscf')`

Comment: @VoidZA  it's Still missing